# How to handle complete change of the Textbox in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

What event I should handle to react to the completed change of the TextBox (i.e. when the user is
finished editing the content of the TextBox)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several methods that you can use: `Leave` event, or a manual "typing stopped" event.

The `Leave` method is the most straight forward way of doing it, although as the event name suggests, it only happens when they `TextBox` looses focus, not when the user stops typing.

The TypingStopped event is something you would need to create yourself, but the basic idea of it is a short duration timer (say 500ms, but you would need to test it), which you restart on every `KeyDown` event of the `TextBox`.  The timer would fire its own event and disable itself if it ever hits the end of it's timeout.

Edit: Updated to `Leave` event as per Hans' recommendation.

Comment: Never use LostFocus, it is a dangerous event.  Check the MSDN article for WM_KILLFOCUS for the reason.  Use the Leave event.  Or Validating when validation is required.

Comment: @HansPassant: I see what you mean on that, updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: I really think Validated is the best option for this.

Answer (score 3):

The `Leave` event is generally a good one for processing user input (for validation for example) as they move on to another part of the form. Just make sure that the event fires if they go from the textbox to any other UI element on your form - you may need to force a focus on the new element.